# Clicking the button from selenium does nothing

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am using python + Selenium to get some data from this website -

https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/indices/historical_index_data.htm

I have selected the index, and set the calendar dates. Now when I click on the "Get Data" button on the website, absolutely nothing happens. If I click the Get Data button manually, I get the data, and a link to a CSV file.

Here's my snippet of code -

```
    indexes = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="indexType"]'))
    indexes.select_by_visible_text("NIFTY 50")
    time.sleep(1)
    
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fromDate"]').click()
    month = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/div/div/select[1]'))
    month.select_by_visible_text('Jan')
    year = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/div/div/select[2]'))
    year.select_by_visible_text('2020')

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/a').click()
    #time.sleep(2)

    today = date.today()
    yesterday = pd.to_datetime(today) - pd.to_timedelta(1, "D")
    m = yesterday.month - 1
    y = yesterday.year  
    #time.sleep(2)
    
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="toDate"]').click()
    month = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/div/div/select[1]'))
    month.select_by_value(str(m))
    year = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/div/div/select[2]'))
    year.select_by_value(str(y))
    e = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/table')
    dates = e.find_elements_by_class_name("ui-state-default")
    for d in dates:
        if d.text == str(yesterday.day):
            ActionChains(driver).click(d).perform()
            break
    
    #time.sleep(2)
    
    element = wait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="get"]')))
    ActionChains(driver).click(element).perform
```

I would welcome any suggestions. Thanks in advance.